# How can I get the approximate address if I have the latitude and longitude with Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I have a device that sends to server latitude and longitude, but I want to make a method that can give me a string with the nearby address(road, street, region...)
I have searched of plugins on http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html but it seems that I can not figure out which one is good for my problem.
Basically i the coordinates to address.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaflet doesn't have reverse geosearch capabilities out of the box. I would check out this Leaflet plugin [here.](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/reverse-geocoding.html) Or check out this [geocoder](https://github.com/sa3m/leaflet-control-bing-geocoder) that uses Bing (you'll need to register a key). On the leaflet [plugin page](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding) there is another that seems like a good fit, ['Leaflet Control Geocoder.'](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder)